# Ask for pin when switching profiles on XBox-one?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network, xbox-game-pass

My (adult) Xbox profile has 3 years of game pass ultimate on it. I’ve set up a Microsoft Family profile/account for my 7 yo son in order to white-list games I would like him to be able to play via my game-pass privileges — like ‘Minecraft’, ‘Roblox’, and ‘Totally Reliable Delivery Service.’

It appears the only way he can use my game-pass privileges is to have my profile signed in at all times and then ‘switch profile’ to his.

I’ve configured my profile to prompt for a passkey/PIN every time I sign-in, but once signed in, my 7 yo can easily ‘switch profile’ back to mine and have access to games not appropriate for his age.

**Is there a way I can have the Xbox One prompt for a password or pin when switching profiles?**

***-- Update --***

I just added 'Screen time' to my son's profile and just as I feared, as soon as his time ran out he immediately switched his profile to mine to circumvent the time limit. I can't even screen time-limit my profile as a work-around because that feature is not available for adult profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to prompt a pin when switching profiles. You only need to input your pin when you sign in and since you already signed in so they could use your account, you wouldn't need to put your pin in again.

But there is a different way to give him access to your gamepass privileges. If you set the Xbox as your home Xbox then your Xbox Gold status and all of your games will be shared with everyone on the Xbox. To set your home Xbox Select Profile & system > Settings > General > Personalization, and then select My home Xbox. This should allow your son to play your games even when you aren't signed in.

Comment: Thank you.  The issue, as you pointed out, was that my Xbox was *not* set as “My Home Xbox.”  Now that I recall, some years ago I changed my home XBox to my fathers Xbox that he only used for Blu-ray’s (and likewise his to mine) so that when my son went over to his grandparents’ house he had access to both libraries of games.  Now that we both have game pass accounts, this is no longer necessary and now my son can access game pass on our local (and now “home”) Xbox without me signed in

Comment: Indeed this solves the problem by eliminating the need for parent to sign in.
Rather obscure solution; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to "Settings" < "Account" < "Sign-in, Security, and Passkey" < "Change my Preferences".
If you have kinect you can choose "Make sure it is me" By you standing in front of kinect every time you sign in.
If you don't have, choose "Require Passkey"

Hope this helps and I didn't understand the question wrongly.

Comment: This is the method I used for the *"I’ve configured my profile to prompt for a password every time I sign-in"* part of my question.  But it does ***not*** re-prompt for the passkey when switching profiles -- that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Okay.. I maybe had some mis-understanding give me some time to answer you.

Comment: Ty, I started a bounty because a soln is very important, especially now that I added screen time.

Comment: 1. Press the Xbox button to open the guide. Then, Select System > Settings > Account.
Then, Select Sign-in, security & passkey. After that, Select Create my passkey.
Now all you have left to do is Enter a 6-digit passkey, and then re-enter the passkey to confirm.

Comment: That is how to do it

Comment: Note that the passkey is like the PIN. Not Password and will require every switch account.

Comment: I’ve done all that.  If I sign in my account (after entering passkey/PIN) and then go to Xbox Guide -> ‘Sign In’ -> ‘Switch Profile’, I can choose my son’s profile and ‘switch profile’ back to mine ***without a re-prompt for the passkey***.  If I ***sign-out*** of my account, then yes, it asks for my passkey again.  But if my profile is signed out, my son will not have access to game-pass games.

Comment: Sorry, I really forgot how to do it.. Can't help you...